# How can I assign this Python variable to the list I am looping through?

Tags: python, for-loop

## Thank you to everyone who has made my first StackOverflow post extremely helpful and fun.

I have been working through this problem all day and have gotten to this point. I have it almost figured out.

**Directions:
Your task is to assign the variable names_and_ranks to a list, with each element equal to the city name and it's corresponding rank. For example, the first element would be, "1. Buenos Aires" and the second would be "2. Toronto". Use a for loop and the lists `city_indices` and `city_names` to accomplish this. We'll need to perform some nifty string interpolation to format our strings properly. Check out f-string interpolation to see how we can pass values into a string. Remember that list indices start at zero, but we want our `names_and_ranks` list to start at one!**

Here is what I have:

The code `city_indices` only gives me "11" so I have made it into a list

```
city_indices = list(range(0, len(cities)))
city_indices

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

```
city_names

['Buenos Aires',
 'Toronto',
 'Marakesh',
 'Albuquerque',
 'Los Cabos',
 'Greenville',
 'Archipelago Sea',
 'Pyeongchang',
 'Walla Walla Valley',
 'Salina Island',
 'Solta',
 'Iguazu Falls']
```

The original code that produced the correct list, but not assigned to the correct variable. The generated list should be assigned to `names_and_ranks`

```
city_indices = -1
names_and_ranks = [city_names[city_indices]]
for elements in city_names:
        city_indices += 1
        print(f'{city_indices+1}. {city_names[city_indices]}')
# write a for loop that adds the properly formatted string to the names_and_ranks list

Returns:

1. Buenos Aires
2. Toronto
3. Marakesh
4. Albuquerque
5. Los Cabos
6. Greenville
7. Archipelago Sea
8. Pyeongchang
9. Walla Walla Valley
10. Salina Island
11. Solta
12. Iguazu Falls
```

**This list is correct with the correct numbering.** However, it does not seem to correspond to the names_and_ranks variable correctly. In fact, when I run:

```
names_and_ranks[0]
```

I get the last item (#12) on my list.... Keep in mind that the **list index** is 0 - 11, but I am numbering the output 0 - 12.

Any ideas? Once I assign this variable and run a successful loop to show a list of cities starting at 1. I will need to print the different elements in the new list.

ie `names_and_ranks[0]` should return "1. Buenos Aires"

Current result from running:

```
names_and_ranks[0] # should return '1. Buenos Aires'



IndexErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-871e7a906308> in <module>
----> 1 names_and_ranks[0] # '1. Buenos Aires'
      2  # '2. Toronto'
      3  # '12. Iguazu Falls'

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Thanks @sshashank124 for the correction

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the issue is, your code seems to work just fine.

Comment: @AMC the code works fine until you go to call elements from names_and_ranks

Comment: @AMC just updated my post to show the result I am getting from running names_and_ranks[1]

Comment: Please share **all** relevant code and data. See: [mcve].

Comment: I think you're missing the part where you add the formatted string to the list `names_and_ranks`. Replace `print(f'{city_indices+1}. {city_names[city_indices]}')` with `names_and_ranks.append(f'{city_indices+1}. {city_names[city_indices]}')`

Comment: It would help if you could show us the contents of `city_indices` and `city_names`

Comment: @Bill updated see above

Comment: @AjayDabas okay you're onto something there. That allows me to call ```names_and_ranks[1]``` and get the correct answer. However, when I ```print(names_and_ranks)``` I get a huge mess. Not the ordered, numbered list.

Comment: @Dave Can you reorganize/merge all these snippets of code into a single [mcve]? It's all over the place and as such isn't entirely clear to me what you're trying to do

Comment: @AMC I reorganized my thread to be a little more cohesive. I think this is a pretty understandable format now.

Comment: @Dave What are the contents of `names_and_ranks`? I see where you define it in your code, I’m just not sure what the result of that would be, or what it’s for.

Comment: I forgot to add that if we could get a solid understanding of what your program is meant to do, we might be able to find a better solution overall.

Answer (score 1):

How about using enumerate? 
You can use index, easily
for example,

```
for index, value in enumerate(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']):
    print(index, value)
```

this returns 
0 foo
1 bar
2 baz

Comment: The directions are specifically asking me for f-string interpolation

Answer (score 0):

here is using f'strings, this returns same as above:

```
city_names = ['Buenos Aires',
 'Toronto',
 'Marakesh',
 'Albuquerque',
 'Los Cabos',
 'Greenville',
 'Archipelago Sea',
 'Pyeongchang',
 'Walla Walla Valley',
 'Salina Island',
 'Solta',
 'Iguazu Falls']

names_and_ranks = []
for index,city in enumerate(city_names):
        names_and_ranks.append(f'{index+1}. {city}')
print(names_and_ranks)
```

output:
    ['1. Buenos Aires', '2. Toronto', '3. Marakesh', '4. Albuquerque', '5. Los Cabos', '6. Greenville', '7. Archipelago Sea', '8. Pyeongchang', '9. Walla Walla Valley', '10. Salina Island', '11. Solta', '12. Iguazu Falls']

EDIT: as the questioner wants names_and_ranks[8] returning '8. Pyeongchang' this is the edit:

```
city_names = ['Buenos Aires',
 'Toronto',
 'Marakesh',
 'Albuquerque',
 'Los Cabos',
 'Greenville',
 'Archipelago Sea',
 'Pyeongchang',
 'Walla Walla Valley',
 'Salina Island',
 'Solta',
 'Iguazu Falls']

names_and_ranks = [0]
city_indices = 1
for city in city_names:
        names_and_ranks.insert(city_indices,f'{city_indices}. {city}')
        city_indices+=1

print(names_and_ranks[8])
```

Comment: This is the return of the code: ```['1.Buenos Aires']
['1.Buenos Aires', '2.Toronto']
['1.Buenos Aires', '2.Toronto', '3.Marakesh']
['1.Buenos Aires', '2.Toronto', '3.Marakesh', '4.Albuquerque']
['1.Buenos Aires', '2.Toronto', '3.Marakesh', '4.Albuquerque', '5.Los Cabos']
['1.Buenos Aires', '2.Toronto', '3.Marakesh', '4.Albuquerque', '5.Los Cabos', '6.Greenville']
['1.Buenos Aires', '2.Toronto', '3.Marakesh', '4.Albuquerque', '5.Los Cabos', '6.Greenville', '7.Archipelago Sea']
['1.Bueno``` etc etc.

Comment: if you use city_names list given by you in the question and run this code and print(names_and_ranks) you will get 
 ['1.Buenos Aires',
 '2.Toronto',
 '3.Marakesh',
 '4.Albuquerque',
 '5.Los Cabos',
 '6.Greenville',
 '7.Archipelago Sea',
 '8.Pyeongchang',
 '9.Walla Walla Valley',
 '10.Salina Island',
 '11.Solta',
 '12.Iguazu Falls']

Comment: This is the return I am getting from that code ```['1. I']```

Comment: My original code gives me the correct return, such that I get a list consisting of the cities in a numbered list starting at 1. ... The problem I am having is assigning it to names_and_ranks then being able to call an element from names_and_ranks.

 For example, if Pyeongchang is #8, and I call ```names_and_ranks[8]``` I should get a return of ```'8. Pyeongchang'```

Comment: please post the full code that gave you this output. I have edited my answer and given the full code use that code in case you are using your code.

Comment: Hi seems like you want to start names_and_ranks list from 1 and not 0 so use this code that i have added now in the answer please see.  this will give you names_and_rank[8] will return you '8. Pyeongchang'

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do:

```
names_and_ranks = [f'{i}. {x}' for i,x in enumerate(l, 1)]

print(names_and_ranks[0])
1. Buenos Aires
```

Answer (score 0):

your entire code is correct except for the first line:

```
city_indices = -1
```

which (is an index, i guess) should start from 0 and NOT from -1.

Reason,

in Python, -1 points to last element of list/string/.. and -2 as second last element and so on.
so, I recommend you should change only:
    city_indices = 0

and then change the further code based on this line.

```
city_indices = 0
names_and_ranks = [city_names[city_indices]]
for elements in city_names:
    print(f'{city_indices+1}. {city_names[city_indices]}')
    city_indices += 1
```

Comment: Actually I just want to point out that when I run ```names_and_ranks[1]``` it is out of range. This is strange. ```names_and_ranks[0]``` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

## I moved on after realizing I probably was spending way too much time on something relatively simple. I found the solutions manual. Here is the correct answer. I hope this might help someone else working on the Learn.co Flatiron School Data Science Pre-Work...

```
names_and_ranks = []
for elements in city_indices:
        names_and_ranks.append(f"{elements + 1}. {city_names[elements]}")

names_and_ranks
```

Comment: What was the issue, in the end? Were you just not appending the elements to the list?

Comment: @AMC one of the problems was I wasn't setting ```names_and_ranks``` as a new, empty variable for a list. My for loop was looping the incorrect list. I was not appending the new values to the variable ```names_and_ranks```. The f-string was also incorrect.